# Multiple level master/detail in ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'd like to do something like this example: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/master-detail-master-rows/. This works perfectly. The problem is that I need to have another level of detail. Right now data from this example comes like this:

```js
[
  {
    "name": "Mila Smith",
          "account": 177001,
          "calls": 24,
          "minutes": 26.216666666666665,
          "callRecords": [{
              "name": "susan",
              "callId": 579,
              "duration": 23,
              "switchCode": "SW5",
              "direction": "Out",
              "number": "(02) 47485405"
          }]
  }
]
```

So there is a master object - a person with callRecords as details. But I would like to do something that handles this:

```js
[
  {
    "stateName": "Arizona",
    "citizens": [
      {
        "name": "Mila Smith",
              "account": 177001,
              "calls": 24,
              "minutes": 26.216666666666665,
              "callRecords": [{
                  "name": "susan",
                  "callId": 579,
                  "duration": 23,
                  "switchCode": "SW5",
                  "direction": "Out",
                  "number": "(02) 47485405"
              }]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

so I would have first dropdown to show citizens of given state and inside it I would like to open info about given citizen. Is this possible?